# Is it possible to display a d3 chart using the mouseover element of another d3 chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I have created a line chart that has a tooltip on that displays the value at that point of the chart. I would also like the tooltip to change another section of the page from some words to displaying another d3 chart. I have been trying to use the function below :

```
function linechange(txt5) {
document.getElementById('name5').innerHTML = txt5;
}
```

I know that the d3 chart i want to call works as when i put:

```
<div id="contract"></div>
```

in the body of my page it display. However as soon as I try and put it in the function above and call the function in the mouseover it won't display. The words disapper and when i inspect the element the div is there but not the chart.

My question is whether this is possible at all? Or am i just being an idiot! (The latter is more likely as I am still trying to get my head around html/d3/javascript)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you should just need to toggle the `display` style of your div.

First put the div code in your body, but set it's display style to "none" in the css or style attribute

```
<div id="contract" style="display:none;"></div>
```

then insert this into your mousover function

```
d3.select("#contract").style("display","inline-block")
```

You may need to use something other than `inline-block` depending on how you want the div displayed in your website.

Then you'll probably need to set the display back to none when you mouseout

```
d3.select("#contract").style("display","none")
```